# Debian boot with encrypted disks: RAID is not assembled

Tags: debian, systemd, raid, mdadm, luks

**[Update: This is fixed with Debian 9]**

**Situation**
I am running Debian 8 on my machine. The disk setup is as follows:

```
# lsblk 
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0  55.9G  0 disk  
├─sda1                      8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0   244M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  55.2G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt            253:0    0  55.2G  0 crypt 
    ├─ssd-root            253:1    0    15G  0 lvm   /
    ├─ssd-swap            253:2    0     4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─ssd-home            253:3    0    15G  0 lvm   /home
    └─ssd-opt             253:4    0    12G  0 lvm   /opt
sdb                         8:16   0 698.7G  0 disk  
└─sdb-crypt               253:5    0 698.7G  0 crypt 
  └─md1                     9:1    0 698.5G  0 raid1 
    ├─crypt--raid-X       253:7    0   300G  0 lvm   /mnt/X
    └─crypt--raid-Y       253:8    0   130G  0 lvm   /mnt/Y
sdc                         8:32   0 698.7G  0 disk  
└─sdc-crypt               253:6    0 698.7G  0 crypt 
  └─md1                     9:1    0 698.5G  0 raid1 
    ├─crypt--raid-X       253:7    0   300G  0 lvm   /mnt/X
    └─crypt--raid-Y       253:8    0   130G  0 lvm   /mnt/Y
```

In short, I have a tiny SSD (`/dev/sda`) which I boot from. The actual OS data, apart from `/boot`, is encrypted.

I also have two HDDs (`/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`) which contain data. Both disks are encrypted individually, and on top of these encrypted devices I run a RAID (using `mdadm`). This RAID device serves as the physical volume (`pv)` for LVM.

**Boot Problem**
When I boot this system, I first have to unlock the SSD (`/dev/sda3`). This works as expected.

After that, I am asked to unlock `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. This is also expected. However, `systemd` then tries to start/find my LVM LVs. These are not available, yet, as the RAID needs to be started first.

As a consequence, I have to wait 1m30sec for a timeout. Then, in the rescue shell, I have to assemble the RAID (`mdadm -As` for scan+assemble is enough). After that, the system boots up without any issues (besides the fact that `eth0` is not brought up, this may be related).

**Question**
How can I convince `systemd` to assemble the RAID before setting up LVM?

**Further Information**

My `mdadm.conf`:

```
DEVICE partitions containers
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes
HOMEHOST <system>
MAILADDR root
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=f331732a:0254455e:faca8755:0ffbd122 name=hostname:1
```

I re-created the grub configuration and the init.rd files while trying to debug this.

Comment: With Debian Stretch (Debian 9, released in June 2017 i.e. today) the problem is different. Now I can boot without manual interaction (additional to the password prompts) and eth0 also works. A third disk I recently added to the set is not re-added automatically on boot, but this may be an unrelated issue.

Comment: The issue with the third disk is fixed, so there's nothing wrong with Debian Stretch. Yay!